# Intersection between line and sphere

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra

I need to find the intersection between a line and a sphere defined by the following equations

**Line:** `P = P0 + tv`, where `P0` is the eye of a camera and v is the direction of a ray.

**Sphere:** `(P - Pc)^T (P - Pc) = r^2`, where `Pc` is the center of the sphere and r is the radius

How would I solve for `t`?

Comment: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/maths/ray-sphere-intersection/  check this link

Comment: Write `P0 = (e, f, g)`, `V = (u, v, w)` and `Pc = (a, b, c)`. Then just substitute all this into the equation. You will end up with a quadratic equation in `t` where the coefficients are polynomials in `e`, `f`, `g`, `u`, `v`, `w`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `r`. You can solve this using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that v is normalized.

The point of closest approach of the line to the center of the sphere occurs at t<sub>1</sub>:

```
v . (P0 + t1 v - Pc) = 0
v . (Pc - P0) = t1
```

At t<sub>1</sub> the distance from the line to the center of the sphere is

```
h = sqrt((Pc - P0)^2 - t1^2)
```

The intersection with the surface of the sphere will occur (if it occurs at all) at t1 +/- td, where

```
td^2 + h^2 = r^2
td^2 = r^2 - h^2
     = r^2 - (Pc - P0)^2 + t1^2
     = r^2 - (Pc - P0)^2 + (v . (Pc - P0))^2
```

Comment: so solving the bottom equation will give the intersection point?

Comment: @compsci45000: if the right-hand side of the last equation is negative, then there are no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First change the coordinates to a system on the sphere center. `P0 -> P0-Pc`

Now you have `P0=(x0,y0,z0)` and the ray coordinates as

```
x = x0+t*vx
y = y0+t*vy
z = z0+t*vz
```

and make sure `ǁvx,vy,vzǁ=1`

The equation of the sphere is `x^2+y^2+z^2-R^2 = 0` which is expanded as

```
t^2 + 2*(vx*x0+vy*y0+vz*z0)*t + (x0^2+y0^2+z0^2-R^2) = 0
t^2 + 2*B*t+C =0 
  B = vx*x0+vy*y0+vz*z0
  C = x0^2+y0^2+z0^2-R^2
t = +√(B^2-C)/2-B
t = -√(B^2-C)/2-B
```

Which gives the two solutions, `p=Pc+P0+v*t` for the two `t` computed.